# How to create a dialog for multiple consecutive entries?

Tags: android

I am currently working on an Android application that can manage a card game. I have (let's say) 4 players and after each round I click a button that opens a dialog to enter the score of the players during this round. How can I achieve this in an opened dialog? I tried several things, for example a ViewFlipper in the dialog, none of them working so far. The ViewFlipper for example doesn't have the chance to go to the next view since the dialog is already closed again when I hit the OK-button.

Comment: you mean to say, you need to open a dialog, to enter user score.. that is what you want to achieve? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a dialog you can use an Activity that has the look and feel of a dialog. To achieve that add this to your Activity definition:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

inside the `<Application>` tag in Android `Manifest.xml`.

**EDIT** To pass data back and forth between your Activities and your Dialog UI Activity, you can use `Intents`. For example, lets say that you want to pass a `String` from CustomActivity to DialogActivity. The code of the CustomActivity would be:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogActivity.class);
i.putExtra("your_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in your DialogActivity to access the data you will use:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String variable_value = extras.getString("your_variable_name");
}
```

Same logic goes when you want to send data form your DialogActivity to your CustomActivity.

You can also use `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` methods to do that. See [here](http://rahulonblog.blogspot.gr/2010/05/android-startactivityforresult-example.html) for more information about those two methods.

Comment: Very interesting suggestion. How do I get the data back and forth between my 2 activities?

Comment: Since the dialog will be an Activity you can simply use Intents.

Comment: Would it maybe be a more elegant solution to use DialogFragments?

Comment: Google recommends the use of DialogFragments so yes it would be more elegant i believe. That does not mean that you cannot use Dialogs. The decision its up to you of course and should depend on what fulfill your needs better.